# Trocar imagem do banner via Central

Tags: php, javascript, html, aplicação-web

Olá, criei uma pagina simples em HTML, com um banner, gostaria de saber como faço para criar uma área de administração para mudar a imagem deste banner.

Código do banner:

```
<div class="slider-style-1">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="overflow-img-banner">
            <img src="assets/img/banner.jpg" class="c-img-banner">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Acho que isto pode ajudar: https://gist.github.com/no1k/8492575. Depois deves guardar o caminho para a nova imagem em algum sitio, ficheiro ou base de dados

Comment: Obrigado amigo!!!!